# Visual Studio 2008 Designer catastrophic failure after change the control name

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am using VS 2008 to develop a winforms application using C++ CLI/CLR. After I chnage the name of one of the control I start to get the following error. even If i delete the control and add new, I still get the same error.

Instances of this error (1)

```
1.   Hide Call Stack 


at EnvDTE.CodeFunction.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart Part)
at Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

Comment: This is not much data to go on.

Comment: This is all the call stack I get

Comment: Part of the error chain is missing; this does not appear to cover the final error. Can you post the section of the code that calls the control?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdesigner/thread/884cc63e-5ee4-4ab9-9771-ac24d58ea8c5

Comment: +1 for cracking me up with "...catastrophic failure"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in VS2008, and I managed to get out of it. I removed all the VS2008 generated files:

```
Solution\Project\app.aps
Solution\Project\Project.vcproj.mymachine.myuser.user
Solution\Solution.suo
Solution\Solution.ncb
```

And hey presto all problems disappeared.